# Call class function with macro

Tags: c++, class, oop, macros

Here i want to call `world` function from class `Hello` with macro `MPRINT()` but it doesn't recognize the macro syntax:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

// first try
#define MPRINT(text) \
    []() -> Hello::world(#text)\
    }()

// second try
#define MPRINT(text) \
Hello obj; \
obj.world(text);

class Hello
{
public:
    string world(string inp);
};

string Hello::world(string inp) {
    return inp + "|test";
}

int main()
{
    string test1 = MPRINT("blahblah"); // error "type name is not allowed"
    cout << MPRINT("blahblah"); // error "type name is not allowed"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why down vote? Can u tell me the reason i will edit if necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first attempt, you are trying to use `Hello::world`, but this is not the correct syntax for calling a non-static member function.

In your second attempt, using `MPRINT` would result in:

```
string test1 = Hello obj; obj.world(text); ;
```

which is also clearly invalid.

You could write the macro like this:

```
#define MPRINT(text)            \
    [] {                        \
       Hello obj;               \
       return obj.world(#text); \
    }()
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/J94SCX).

That being said, I *strongly* suggest that you don't use macros for this sort of thing. The following function works perfectly well:

```
auto MPRINT(std::string text) 
{                        
  Hello obj;               
  return obj.world(text); 
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/uDwVeg).

Comment: Thanks it worked :) . It just confuses me why there is nothing on internet about my question. Right a little more explanation on overall how to call from namespace and class will help many people as well.

Comment: Can i do that without creating object? like calling with `Hello::world()` inside that lambda. Does it creates a object every time i call `MPRINT` ?

Comment: No, and that has nothing to do with macros. Non-static member functions need an object for them to be called on.